# Website migration

Tags: webserver, https, letsencrypt

I have a website on a home linux box (Rasperry Pi2B). It is mailnly for my own use, but is exposed to the world, uses a Dynamic DNS service, HTTPS with a LetsEncrypt certificate, which renews automatically.

I want to transfer it over to my new computer (new Pi 4B). The old one will then be disconnected. I have got the Apache/PHP/MariaDB stack up and running and checked that my website works fine on localhost. Now I need to migrate it to being the site as seen from outside. I remember it being quite a bit of work to set up, but that was some time ago now and all rather hazy. Certbot, LetsEncrypt, sites-enabled etc etc.

I can read it all up again and work through it step by step, but if anyone can point me to any shortcuts - key files I can just copy over (without breaking things), other things that I shall need to do from scratch etc. then that would be very helpful. The last step I expect will be to change my router's port forwarding to point to the new Pi, but there is much to do before that I think.